# Image mapping not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, imagemap

Here I'm using image mapping.but the problem is when I change the width and height of the image then it's not working on image some circle I draw when I hover the circle `hover-content1` appears.
Image: [image]

After not getting using image mapping.
I tried on hover to the circle `hover-content1` `opacity: 1` mouseout `opacity: 0`.But unfortunately this is also not working.

**Can anyone suggest me how to do this using CSS or jquery no problem?**

```css
.headset-image{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 200px;
}
.headset-image img {
 position: relative;
 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
}
.hover-wrapper {
 /*position: relative;*/
}
.hover-wrapper .hover-content1,
.hover-wrapper .hover-content2,
.hover-wrapper .hover-content3,
.hover-wrapper .hover-content4 {
    display: flex;
    width: 10%;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: justify;
}
h4.hover-head-content {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px 4px 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
p.hover-para-content {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.40;
}
.hover-content1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 13%;
    padding: 5px;
 opacity: 1;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.hover-content2 {
 position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 16%;
    padding: 5px;
 opacity: 1;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.hover-content3 {
 position: absolute;
    top: 58%;
    left: 36%;
    padding: 5px;
 opacity: 1;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.hover-content4 {
 position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    left: 36%;
    padding: 5px;
 opacity: 1;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.loading-content1:hover .hover-content1 {
 opacity: 1;
}
/* circle animation */
.loading-content1 .loading-circles {
 position:absolute;
 left:19%;
 top:37%;
}
.loading-content2 .loading-circles {
 position:absolute;
 left:29%;
 top:53%;
}
.loading-content3 .loading-circles {
 position:absolute;
 left:37%;
 top:50%;
}
.loading-content4 .loading-circles {
 position:absolute;
 left:38%;
 bottom: 65%;
}
.loading-circles > .circle{
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 height: 15px;
 width: 15px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
 transform-origin: 0 0; 
 -webkit-transform: scale(1,1)translate(-50%,-50%);
 transform: scale(1,1)translate(-50%,-50%);
 -webkit-animation: fade 1s linear infinite;
 animation: fade 1s linear infinite;
 background: red;
 opacity: 1;
}
.circle.hold{
 -webkit-animation:none;
}
.circle.first+.circle{
 -webkit-animation-delay:.33s;
 animation-delay:.33s;
}
.circle.first+.circle+.circle{
 -webkit-animation-delay:.66s;
 animation-delay:.66s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from{
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1,1)translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
  to{
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:scale(2,2)translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from{
    opacity:1;
    transform:scale(1,1)translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
  to{
    opacity:0;
    transform:scale(2,2)translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section-image">

  <div class="headset-image">
   <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/iVKhMm/headset.jpg" class="headphone" alt="">
  </div>

  <!-- hover-effect-1 -->
  <div class="hover-wrapper">
   <div class="loading-content1">
    <div class="loading-circles">
     <div class="circle hold"></div>
     <div class="circle first"></div>
     <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="hover-content1">
    <h4 class="hover-head-content">ACOUSTIC NOISE CANCELLING</h4>
    <p class="hover-para-content">
     More than 40 years of noise-cancelling obsession makes quiet sound quieter and music sound better.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- hover-effect-2 -->
  <div class="hover-wrapper">
   <div class="loading-content2">
    <div class="loading-circles">
     <div class="circle hold"></div>
     <div class="circle first"></div>
     <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="hover-content2">
    <h4 class="hover-head-content">ACOUSTIC NOISE CANCELLING</h4>
    <p class="hover-para-content">
     More than 40 years of noise-cancelling obsession makes quiet sound quieter and music sound better.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- hover-effect-3 -->
  <div class="hover-wrapper">
   <div class="loading-content3">
    <div class="loading-circles">
     <div class="circle hold"></div>
     <div class="circle first"></div>
     <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="hover-content3">
    <h4 class="hover-head-content">ACOUSTIC NOISE CANCELLING</h4>
    <p class="hover-para-content">
     More than 40 years of noise-cancelling obsession makes quiet sound quieter and music sound better.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- hover-effect-4 -->
  <div class="hover-wrapper">
   <div class="loading-content4">
    <div class="loading-circles">
     <div class="circle hold"></div>
     <div class="circle first"></div>
     <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="hover-content4">
    <h4 class="hover-head-content">ACOUSTIC NOISE CANCELLING</h4>
    <p class="hover-para-content">
     More than 40 years of noise-cancelling obsession makes quiet sound quieter and music sound better.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagemap is not responsive, but you can use any plugin to make it responsive. I have used this one with good results:

https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps

You also have:

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/imagemap-resizer